# lighttpd - reject a connection based on the value of the client cert CN discovered during ssl negotiation. (ssl.verifyclient)

Tags: authentication, ssl-certificate, client-server, lighttpd

I want to drop or reject a connection based on the value of the client cert CN discovered during ssl negotiation.
I'm not familiar with syntax and can't find similar examples.

I'm stuck with *lighttpd v.1.4.45*.

In a mixture of real and pseudocode:

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":443" {
  ssl.engine = "enable"
  ...
  ssl.ca-file =  "..."
  ...
  # client side authentification       
  ssl.verifyclient.activate = "enable"
  ssl.verifyclient.enforce = "enable"
  ssl.verifyclient.depth = "2"
  # this line instructs client cert CN value to be extracted
  ssl.verifyclient.username = "SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN"  
}
# psuedocode
<client CN> <not regexp-equal> <regexp> {
  <reject>
}
```

**Can it be done at the *lighttpd* level?  Assume going down to application code is not an option.**

(I'm also curious to see an example of how could it be done at application level but that is not the primary question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lighttpd mod_auth.  https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModAuth

```
server.modules += ("mod_auth")
auth.require = ( "" =>
                 (
                   "method"  => "extern",
                   "realm"   => "certificate",
                   "require" => "user=agent007|user=agent008" 
                 )
               )
```

You have to list the permitted SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN values in `user=...|user=...`

Comment: Brilliant!  Like magic.  I just pasted that into a file /etc/lighttpd/conf-available/02-auth-cert.conf, linked it to conf-enabled, and it worked.
I looked on the man page you referenced, and couldn't see that example or a reference to "extern" or "certificate". You have super powers.

Comment: I should also mention that wildcard "*" doesn't seem to work in the "requires" right hand side values.

Comment: It should be noted that wildcard "*" is not present in the documentation: https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModAuth  Why did you post that you assumed it would work without providing a link to the documentation?  If you want to allow any authenticated user, then use "require" => "valid-user" as is documented.

Comment: I think no wildcat chars is perfectly satisfactory.  I only mentioned it because I asked in my original question and wanted to cross the t's.  In the original question I was imaging it as the counterpart to the server domain wildcard feature - e.g. `*.example.com`.  Of course there are security risk to wildcat server certs - and there would be corresponding risks in wildcat character IDs for clients, so we're better off without them.
---- Anyway, I want to thank you again for your help!

Comment: Also thank you for conscientiously updating the [ModAuth documentation](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModAuth).